# Gaussian Integration, Trouble with Error Function

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral, error-function

I'm tasked with evaluating this integral for class:

> $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / (2\sigma^2)} \, dx$, assume $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are real scalars and $\sigma^2 > 0$.

At one point in my solution, I come up against the error function. I've gone over the math a few times and can't seem to figure out what happens. It'll be obvious where my question is in the work below.
Let the Gaussian integral equal $I$ such that

---

Firstly, take $a = 1/(2\sigma^2)$, $u = x-\mu$, $ du = dx$. Notice that when $x=0$, $u=-\mu$. Now, the integral we must solve is the following:
\begin{equation}
    \int_{0}^\infty 
        e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / (2\sigma^2)} 
    \, dx
        =
            \int_{-\mu}^\infty
                e^{-a u^2}
            \, du
    \nonumber
\end{equation}
To further simplify this expression, take $t = \sqrt{a} \, u$. Note that when $u = \mu$, $t = -\sqrt{a} \, \mu$. Then,
\begin{align}
    \int_{-\mu}^\infty
        e^{-a u^2}
    \, du  
        &=
            \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{-\mu \sqrt{a}}^\infty
                e^{-t^2}
            \, dt
        \nonumber
        \\[.5em]
        &=
            \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{-\mu \sqrt{a}}^0
                e^{-t^2} 
            \, dt
            +
            \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{0}^\infty
                e^{-t^2}
            \, dt
        \nonumber
        \\[.5em]
        &=
            -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_0^{-\mu \sqrt{a}}
                e^{-t^2} 
            \, dt
            +
            \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{0}^\infty
                e^{-t^2}
            \, dt.
        \label{eq:hw1_prob1.2}
\end{align}
We should pause here and take a look at each expression in the sum separately. First, we should note the expression of the Error Function,  \begin{equation}
    Erf(z) 
        =
            \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^z e^{-t^2} \, dt.
    \nonumber
\end{equation}
Applying this to the first expression in our sum, we have

---

**BREAK**

At this point in my work, I assume the following expression is true. I know the final answer is correct, but unless $-Erf(-z) = Erf(z)$ (I'm not sure this is true), I'm not sure why this works.

---

\begin{equation}
    -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int_0^{-\mu \sqrt{a}}
            e^{-t^2} 
        \, dt
        =
            \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a} \,}Erf{\left(\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right)}
    \nonumber
\end{equation}

Now, let's turn our focus to the second sum. Using the 'polar' method of solving this expression, we have
\begin{align}
    I 
        &=
            \int_0^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt
        =
            \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2} \, dt
    \nonumber
    \\[.5em]
    I^2
        &=
            \dfrac{1}{4}  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \, dx dy.
    \nonumber
\end{align}
Take $x = r\cos{\theta}$, $y = r \sin \theta$, $
dx dy = r \, dr d\theta$ such that
\begin{equation}
    \dfrac{1}{4} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
        r e^{-r^2} \, dr d\theta.
    \nonumber
\end{equation}
Now, let $u = -r^2$ so that $du = -2 r dr$. So,
\begin{equation}
    I^2 
        =
            -\dfrac{1}{8} 2\pi \int_0^\infty e^u \, du
        =
            \dfrac{\pi}{4},
    \nonumber
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    I 
        =
        \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.
    \nonumber
\end{equation}

Putting this all together and skipping over some tedious algebra, we have
\begin{equation}
\boxed{
    \int_{0}^\infty e^{-(x-\mu)^2 / (2\sigma^2)} \, dx
        =
            \sigma \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \left[ 1 + Erf\left(\dfrac{\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right) \right]
}
\nonumber
\end{equation}

---

Any help with this is appreciated. I'm sure it's a simple mistake that I am overlooking.

Comment: It is true that $-\text{erf}(-x) = \text{erf}(x)$, which can be seen by making the substitution $x \to -x$.

Comment: phew, thank you. If you write out a solution, I'll mark you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is unnecessarily complicated.   $\int_Re^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}dx=\int_Re^{(-y^2)/(2\sigma^2)}dy=\sigma \int_Re^{-u^2/2}du=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$

The error function is needed when you integrate over part of the real line.

Comment: I know, but I needed to show it in the form with the error function.

Comment: Split the integral into $(-\infty ,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ Each part will contain erf term which will add up to simple sum.